# How can I blur part of TMP text and animate that blur in Unity?

Tags: unity, animation, text-mesh-pro

I have a text animation in unity and at one point I want to blur part of the text. How would I do this without creating bunch of material preset and if I would make an effect with editing the material how would I edit the material with animator because it seams it is not editable in animation window.